# Pairwise column summary with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset:

```
d = structure(list(g0 = c(9L, -1L, 7L, 13L, 10L, 13L), g1 = c(10L, 
2L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 10L), g2 = c(5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I want to know the frequency of pairs of values for each sequential pair of columns. And I was wondering if this was possible to do in a single step with dplyr?

i.e. what is the frequency of paired values for g0 & g1, and what is the frequency of paired values for g1 & g2.

The result would have 13 & 10 occuring twice in the first set and everything other combination as 1, and 10 & 5 occuring twice in the second set and everything else as 1.

Comment: Is 9-10 same as 10-9 combo?

Comment: no, those would need to be different. Sorry - I should have treated the values as unique characters across columns.

Comment: Can you post expected output for this data? Is it just 2 columns and the count?

Comment: I guess the ideal would be 4 columns: c1: concatenated columns (eg. g0g1) c2: value g1, c3: value g0, c4 count. Does that make sense?

Comment: row bind 1:2 and 2:3, then use group by as usual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste two columns 1:2 and 2:3, then get frequency:

```
data.frame(table(c(paste("g0_g1", d$g0, d$g1), paste("g1_g2", d$g1, d$g2))))
#          Var1 Freq
# 1  g0_g1 -1 2    1
# 2  g0_g1 10 2    1
# 3 g0_g1 13 10    2
# 4  g0_g1 7 10    1
# 5  g0_g1 9 10    1
# 6  g1_g2 10 2    2
# 7  g1_g2 10 5    2
# 8   g1_g2 2 2    2
```

More dynamic solution:

```
do.call("rbind", 
        lapply(seq(ncol((d)) - 1), function(i){ 
          cbind(grp = paste(colnames(d)[ c(i, i + 1) ], collapse = "_"),
                data.frame(table(paste(d[, i], d[, i + 1]))))
        }))

#     grp  Var1 Freq
# 1 g0_g1  -1 2    1
# 2 g0_g1  10 2    1
# 3 g0_g1 13 10    2
# 4 g0_g1  7 10    1
# 5 g0_g1  9 10    1
# 6 g1_g2  10 2    2
# 7 g1_g2  10 5    2
# 8 g1_g2   2 2    2
```

Comment: ok great. thanks. How do I know from this which are from the first two columns and which are from the second two columns? 

My real example uses many pairs of columns, so how does this scale?

Comment: @SamPassmore ok, edited, should work for any number of columns.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` approach could be to loop over the columns, `select` 2 columns at a time, add the column name, combine the value using `unite` and `count` their occurrences.

```
library(dplyr)

purrr::map_df(seq_along(d[-1]), ~d %>%
                                 select(.x, .x + 1) %>%
                                 mutate(col = paste(names(.), collapse = "_")) %>%
                                 tidyr::unite(value, 1:2) %>%
                                 count(col, value))


# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  col   value     n
#  <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 g0_g1 -1_2      1
#2 g0_g1 10_2      1
#3 g0_g1 13_10     2
#4 g0_g1 7_10      1
#5 g0_g1 9_10      1
#6 g1_g2 10_2      2
#7 g1_g2 10_5      2
#8 g1_g2 2_2       2
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably better to reshape wide-to-long, then shift, then get group by counts.

Using *data.table*:

```
library(data.table)

melt(data.table(d),
     variable.name = "c1", value.name = "v1"
     )[,
       .(grp = paste(c1, shift(c1, -nrow(d))),
         v1,
         v2 = shift(v1, -nrow(d)))
       ][ !is.na(v2), .(cnt = .N), by = .(grp, v1, v2)]


#      grp v1 v2 cnt
# 1: g0 g1  9 10   1
# 2: g0 g1 -1  2   1
# 3: g0 g1  7 10   1
# 4: g0 g1 13 10   2
# 5: g0 g1 10  2   1
# 6: g1 g2 10  5   2
# 7: g1 g2  2  2   2
# 8: g1 g2 10  2   2
```

Similarly using *dplyr*:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(d, 1:3) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  transmute(grp = paste(name, lead(name, nrow(d))),
            v1 = value,
            v2 = lead(value, nrow(d))) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(v2)) %>% 
  group_by(grp, v1, v2) %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#   grp      v1    v2     n
#   <chr> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 g0 g1    -1     2     1
# 2 g0 g1     7    10     1
# 3 g0 g1     9    10     1
# 4 g0 g1    10     2     1
# 5 g0 g1    13    10     2
# 6 g1 g2     2     2     2
# 7 g1 g2    10     2     2
# 8 g1 g2    10     5     2
```